# How to read data from a txt file into rows and columns for avergae calculatins Python

Tags: python-3.x, post-processing

So I'm using PIV (openPiv) to process images. After processing and saving the data I get a .txt file with three columns x y V:

x: 44 88 132 44 88 132
y: 100 100 100 50 50 50
V: 5 0 2 3 6 7

I need to draw a graph of x vs V but for the same value of x I have 2 values of V so I want to average over 2.
I am therfore trying to write a code in python that can read the value of x in the file and bring back all the related V values so i can sum and average them. Let's say it reads x=44, goes to the file and se that for x=44, v=5 and 3.

Help would be much appriciated 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
file=pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep='\t')
velocity_along_x=file.groupby('x')['V'].mean()
velocity_along_x.plot()
```

I found a simpler way using Pandas

Answer (score 0):

```
fl=open("fileq.txt",'r+')
read_file=fl.read()
ls2=[]
x=0
y=1
V=2
ls_of_ls=[]
sepr=read_file.split('\n')
for items in sepr:
    items=items.split(':')[1]
    ls2.append(items)
for items in ls2:
    ls_of_ls.append(list(map(int,items.split())))
len_inp=len(ls_of_ls[x])
k=int(input("for value x: "))
print("V= ",end='')
for i in range(len_inp):
    if k==ls_of_ls[x][i]:
        print(ls_of_ls[V][i],end=" ")
```

i have written this code according to the given format in text file i.e

x: 44 88 132 44 88 132

y: 100 100 100 50 50 50

V: 5 0 2 3 6 7

just replace fileq.txt with your file

If you want the code for vertical format, i can do that for you.

Comment: Thank you very much it was really helpful,I started witha similar logic but didn't know how to proceed (due to my limited experience in python); my file is indeed vertical format but no worries I'll try to make it work by myself (need to improve my skills). Thanks again for the help I really appreciate it